# Copy Treeview selected Item WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a `Treeview` in my WPF application. I need to copy the elements in my treeview.

```
private void copyCmdBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set text to clip board 
    TreeView tvi = (TreeView)sender;
    Clipboard.SetText(tvi.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

But here the `tvi.SelectedValue` wouldn't return the text which i selected in my treeview. How can i get the text value i selected in my `treeview`.

Update:

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="treeView1" 
          SelectedItemChanged="treeView1_SelectedItemChanged">
    <TreeView.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" 
                        Executed="copyCmdBinding_Executed" 
                        CanExecute="copyCmdBinding_CanExecute"/>
    </TreeView.CommandBindings>
    //Tree elements
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
((TreeViewItem)tvi.SelectedItem).Header.ToString())
```

in general this code may be useful:

```
((T1)tvi.SelectedItem).P.ToString()) 
// T1: type of property that is binded, 
// P: proper method or property that hold the string content
```

Comment: so Items in your tree are not TreeViewItem. can you say what are they?

Comment: try something like this to find out what they are.
MessageBox.Show(this.tvi.SelectedItem.GetType().ToString());

Comment: in the `treeView1_SelectedItemChanged` write this line
`MessageBox.Show(this.tvi.SelectedItem.GetType().ToString());`
so we can understand what they are.

Comment: @Hossien : It will just return the type of the property i binded to Treeview. Not the selected value

Comment: Yeah r8 it will be usefull. But that is my question. What is that P??

Comment: If you don't tell me what `T1` is, how can I tell you what `P` is?

Comment: Thanks a lot..:) (tvi.SelectedItem as T1).P.ToString() Worked fine..:)

Answer (score 0):

Items in your tree can be of any type, and `SelectedValue` returns the Value of the property specified by `SelectedValuePath` of the `SelectedItem`. 
So, make sure you have set `SelectedValuePath` in the Treeview!